# Recursive merge sort in C and memory allocation

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, mergesort

Trying to set up a merge sorting recursive function in C, I came up with the following.

The strange behavior is that, when the size of the array is small (around 10), it works perfectly fine. For sizes from 10 to 15, it sometimes incorrectly sorts (one or two values get randomly placed in the final array), and for values superior to 15, it always sorts one or two values incorrectly, and replaces one or two integer values with a very large negative integer.

For instance, this array : `[3] [9] [2] [11] [8] [7] [5] [2]`

Gets sorted like that : `[2] [2] [3] [-254587859] [7] [8] [11]`

--

Here is the code I came up with :

**main() :**

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int size = atoi(av[1]);
    int *array = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { array[i] = rand() % size; }

    merge_sort(array, 0, size-1);

    print_array(array, size);

    free(array);

    return 0;

}
```

**merge_sort() :**

```
void merge_sort(int array[], int beg, int end)
{
    int mid = (end + beg) / 2;

    if (beg < end)
    {
        merge_sort(array, beg, mid);
        merge_sort(array, mid+1, end);
        merge(array, beg, mid, end);
    }

    return;
}
```

**merge() :**

```
void merge(int array[], int beg, int mid, int end)
{
    int size_left = mid - beg + 1;
    int size_right = end - mid;
    int *left = malloc((size_left)*sizeof(int));
    int *right = malloc((size_right)*sizeof(int));
    int i,j,k;

    for (i = 0; i < size_left; i++) { left[i] = array[beg+i]; }
    for (j = 0; j < size_right; j++) { right[j] = array[mid+1+j]; }

    i = 0; j = 0; for (k = beg; k <= end; k++) { array[k] = (left[i] <= right[j]) ? left[i++] : right[j++]; }

    free(left); free(right);

    return;
}
```

I guess it is a memory allocation problem, and I could allocate loads of memory (I tried, and it works) but it's just not the point. Do you have any idea of what is happening there ?

Config : gcc 4.6.2, Windows 7 64 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is line:

```
for (int k = beg; k <= end; k++) {
    array[k] = (left[i] <= right[j]) ? left[i++] : right[j++];
}
```

Consider `left = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and `right = [5, 6, 7, 8]`. The left will be taken until `i = 4` then you try to reference `left[4]` which is beyond the array and have undetermined value (in Java or other safe languages you would get IndexOutOfBoundException or similar error - in C you are on your own and you have just read some random memory).

You need to ensure that `i` and `j` are within array bounds. For example:

```
 for (int k = beg; k <= end; k++) {
    if (i == size_left) {
        array[k] = right[j++];
    } else if (j == size_right) {
        array[k] = left[i++];
    } else {
        array[k] = (left[i] <= right[j]) ? left[i++] : right[j++];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately such errors are quite common in C. There are tools, both free and commercial, that allows you to find them. For Linux the [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is usually used. CLang or gcc 4.8.0+ AddressSanitizer would also help with this problem - unfortunately I don't know any free tools for Windows other then it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your merge:

```
array[k] = (left[i] <= right[j]) ? left[i++] : right[j++];
```

This does not account for the fact that `i` or `j` might be past the end of the array.  You need to actually check:

```
i = j = 0;
k = beg;

// Merge both
while( i < size_left && j < size_right ) {
    array[k++] = (left[i] <= right[j]) ? left[i++] : right[j++];
}

// Merge leftovers
while( i < size_left ) array[k++] = left[i++];
while( j < size_right ) array[k++] = left[j++];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you Maciej and Paddy, you pointed such a big failure in my reasoning about the "merge" step. That's precisely what comes interesting with C, the sense that you're "on your own" and no guidelines are here to stop you if you make a wrong move.

Based on your improvements, here is what I ended with :

```
for (k = beg; k <= end; k++) {
    array[k] = (left[i] <= right[j]) ?
        (i == size_left) ? right[j++] : left[i++] :
        (j == size_right) ? left[i++] : right[j++];
}
```

Comment: It is  still problematic - the `left[i] <= right[j]` might accesses the arrays beyond the boundaries if `i == size_left` or `j == size_right`. This is undefined behaviour so it is teoretically unsound. Even in practice it might crash if the circumstances are right - for example array ends at page boundary and next page is unmapped.

Comment: For example [GCC 4.8](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/918) would break the above code (only preview version but it is allowed to do).